# MVC ViewModel binding for collection properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

When a model is passed to view, the view has access to all data inside that model. But only for first time. When the view page is submitted say by clicking a submit button , then you don't get any data in the controller. For this you need to explicitly bind each and every model item either by giving a control to populate it or by using Html.HiddenFor(..)

But if my model is having a collection member which in turn having collection member .. upto level 3 or 4, then do I "have to" bind each and every member of these collections in order to get all data in action method after submit? If I am not displaying all these collections items on a view, then why should I bind it by writing huge code? But then I need them in the action method too. Is there any other simpler way to accomplish this other than explicitly binding it on view?

Following is the structure I have.

SalesModel
....IList HomeProducts
....int SalesID

Products
....int ProductID
....IList SecurityProducts

SecurityProduct
....SecurityProductID
....Description
....Price
....IList ProductFeatures

~ SalesModel is boud to aspx (View).
~ From this view, I have called partial view to show Home products (with model=Product).
~ From this partial view I have called another partial view (with model=SecurityProduct).
~ When I first time open the view, I get data at every level. But when I submit the view using submit button, then I dont get anything in SecurityProduct collection evern after binding every thing in FOR loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for different way of handling this see http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2):

yes, great example here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul.. very good post indeed..
Does that mean, I still need to have HiddenFor() for each element in collection and its sub-collections, but using string.format ? Or am I not really understood it yet?

Comment: I have added the model structure I am working on. And now I am not getting any data at any level after submit.. I have bound each field using Html.HiddenFor(...)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : by having hidden fields on both, the root level aspx and the child level ascx. Don't know how this resolves it but it solved the problem.